# mypy types and optional filtering

Tags: python, types, mypy

New to mypy and I'm having trouble finding the right way to get types working when filtering optionals from collections.

```
from typing import Optional, List

list1: List[Optional[int]] = [1, None, 3]
# This type is an error, filter can't even handle a list with optionals
list2: List[int] = list(filter(lambda n: n is not None, list1))
```

Should I be casting this? Should mypy be able to infer that None is filtered out now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `typing.cast` should work, but I think the best solution here is to use a list comprehension.

The following code passes mypy for me:

```
from typing import Optional, List

list1: List[Optional[int]] = [1, None, 3]
list2: List[int] = [x for x in list1 if x is not None]
```

And in general, list comprehensions are the more idiomatic way of expressing mapping/filtering operations. (Guido actually wanted to remove `map`/`filter` in Python 3!)